# Generate a word document with mail merged fields based on list column values

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, word

Im developing a Mobile phone request/asset log system and the final stage of the process is to produce a document detailing the phones details for the user with the usage policy on to be signed by the end user.

The majority of this document is a template but there are some fields that have all been noted within sharepoint already and it seems silly having to copy and paste the users name or phone number if the information has already been entered.

Is there any type of solution out there to mail merge a word document on an item by item basis? I understand that one option would be to export the list to excel and use it as a data source but it would be much handier to do this per item.

We are using Office 365 and Word 2013 if that helps in anyway

Not sure how much would be involved in something like that but any guidence would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use "Quick Parts" inside of Word to display column values from SharePoint.
You will need to create all the column information you need for the document library, and create the Word template for this document library.
You can then "Insert > Quick Parts" from inside of Word and your columns will be shown as options to insert into your Word document.  It works similar to a Mail merge, but with SharePoint list columns.

Here is an article that should help:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields.aspx

Comment: Hi thank you so much, this looks like exactly what im after, ive followed the instructions to the letter but seem to be having a problem with the work flow and im not sure what im doing wrong. im not sure if ive done something wrong between converting the instrcutions from SPD 2007 TO 2013 but im getting a suspended workflow error stating...

Comment: RequestorId: 4625bb77-b4c5-8f87-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt) at System.Double.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider) at Microsoft.Activities.Expressions.ParseNumber`1.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance,...

Comment: ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) Exception from activity ParseNumber<Double> Cast<Double,Object> BuildDictionary<String,Object> Subroutine<Guid> Then If Stage 1 Sequence Flowchart Sequence Generate EPF.WorkflowXaml_8b1000e9_f59a_48be_bd61_1851a3c3c1e8

Comment: Not to worry i resolved the issue! the document template was .dotx instead of .docx

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great new solution that gives this functionality with no code and from within the SharePoint list - SharePoint Document Merge.

Available on the Office Store - https://store.office.com/WA104379659.aspx

Available for SharePoint 2013 / 2010 - https://sharepointdocumentmerge.com